# MongoDB $near is not allowed inside of a $match aggregation expression

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to get the Post that is posted nearby to a given point.
but it shows this error `$near is not allowed inside of a $match aggregation expression`

also tried $geoNear but it shows error `$geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context`

I am not using maxDistance because I don't want to limit it to any radius.

```
exports.getAllPosts = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query);
    var limit = 10;
    var page = req.query.page;
    var query_str = {};
    var cat = req.query.cat;
    var lat = parseInt(req.query.lat);
    var lng = parseInt(req.query.lng);

   
    Post.paginate({ location: {
           $near: {
               $geometry: {
                   type: "Point",
                   coordinates: [lng, lat]
                }
           }
        }},{
        sort: { created_at : 'desc' },
        page: page,
        limit: limit,
    }, function(err, Posts) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: "No Posts found",
                error: err
            });
            return;
        } else {
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: "Post found",
                data: Posts
            });
            return;
        }
    });
};
```

this code works fine in another controller but shows error in this.

Comment: how about just location: { $near: [lng, lat] }?

Comment: Doesn't work still showing the same error.